# WebMethod works fine on live site and localhost, but 404s on second live site

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke, webmethod

I've been beating my head against the wall for hours on this one. This is under DotNetNuke 6.2.5 on a Amazon Web Services Win 2008 R2 server and IIS 7.5.

I have a two WebMethods that live in ~\App_Code\DataService.cs, which has it's companion ~\DataService.asmx. This works great on localhost (where I do my development) and on a live site. I can get the data both in the browser and via AJAX.

The problem is, I need this code to live on a second live server, with basically the same setup as the one where it already works. When I browse on this server to localhost/DataService.asmx, I see the DataService, listing the two WebMethods, but when I click through on them, and then on 'Invoke', I get:

```
404 Not Found<br>The requested Url (http://localhost/DataService.asmx/WebMethod) does not return any valid content.
```

AFAIK, IIS is configured identically, and the web.config files on both machines are virtually identical, certainly as far as the .asmx service mappings are concerned, etc.

I've searched here and elsewhere online. This is killing me. I don't even know where to begin to track down the problem. Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be, or how I can get more information to track it down?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone else... The site had a URL rewriting module from iFinity that was somehow rewriting the URL to something that didn't exist. Dang, I wasted HOURS... hope it helps someone else.